# AWS File Sharing Services With Temporary Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, persistence, file-storage

I am currently looking for a solution to store temporary files in AWS. I want to create a functionality on my app that allows my customers to upload a file and send it by email (something like WeTranfer or Send Anywhere).
I want to save the file temporarily on my AWS storage, for 10 hours and then remove it permanently. If the file has not expired, the user can click the link (provided by AWS) on the email and download the file.

I recently came across S3 Bucket Lifecycle rules, but I can only specify days for the expiration and not hours.
I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: When you say "my app", is it a mobile app, a website or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is the appropriate place to store these files.

If you want access controls (to control which users can access the file) and fine-grained control over when the object 'expires', then you would need to code this yourself.

The files should be stored in a private Amazon S3 bucket. You would then need a back-end app that manages user authentication. When an authorized user requests access to a file, the app can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3 (eg 10 hours). This is the link you would put into the email.

Deletion could still be handled by S3 Lifecycle rules, but it is less important when the file is actually deleted because the pre-signed URL would block access to the file after 10 hours anyway.